# How to convert a string to a list in python for a range(1,10)

Tags: python

In python there is a method called `range()` which defines a list, for example:

```
>>> a = range(1,10)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> type(a)
<type 'list'>
```

I have a configuration file like this:

```
[ports]
scan_range = 1,10
```

Output:

```
1,10
<type 'str'>
```

I want read this configuration file and use this to generate the arguments for the range() method - how do I do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then you need split the string and run `range()` yourself:

```
>>> val = '1,10'
>>> range(*map(int, val.split(',')))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

[`str.split(',')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) split the string by `,` and gives a list which is `[1, 10]`. And then we use `*` to use it as the arguments of `range()` function so it's `range(1, 10)`. Which gives the expected output.